# Add table columns to select without adding it to select_from

Tags: python, database, sqlalchemy, gino

I have a prepared function in the database, which I want to call using Gino. This function has a return type equal to one of the tables, that is created using declarative. What I try to do is:

```
select(MyModel).select_from(func.my_function);
```

The problem is, that SQLAlchemy automatically detects the table in my `select` and adds it implicitly to `select_from`. The resulting SQL contains both my function and the table name in the `FROM` clause and the result is a cartesian of the function result and the whole table (not what I want really).

My question is – can I somehow specify that I want to select all the columns for a model *without* having the corresponding class in the `FROM`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to specify the columns (as an array) if you don't want SA to automatically add `MyModel` to the `FROM` clause.

You have to either do this:

```
select([your_model_table.c.column1, your_model_table.c.column2]).select_from(func.my_function);
```

Your if you want all columns:

```
select(your_model_table.columns).select_from(func.my_function);
```

Comment: With the declarative that would be `MyModel.__table__.columns`. Thanks.